Adding a linear term to the quantum harmonic oscillator.
The problem asks to find the Eigen-states and Energies- for a harmonic oscillator in the potential $V(x) = ax^2+bx$

I first start with the Schrödinger equation:
\begin{equation}
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2\Psi(x)}{dx^2}+V(x)\Psi (x) = E \Psi (x)
\end{equation}
I already know the solution for a potential $V(x) = \alpha x^2$ so I figured I should try to transform variables.
So let $y = x + \frac{b}{2a}$ therefore:
\begin{equation}
V(x) = a\Big(x+\frac{b}{2a}\Big)^2-\frac{b^2}{4a^2} = ay^2-\frac{b^2}{4a^2}\end{equation}
Also let $\chi (x) = \Psi(x-\frac{b}{2a}) $ therefore:
\begin{equation}
\Psi (x) = \chi \Big(x+\frac{b}{2a} \Big) = \chi(y)
\end{equation}
Now I only need to take care of the derivative:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\Psi(x)}{dx} = \frac{d\chi(y)}{dx} = \frac{d\chi(y)}{dx} \underbrace{\frac{dx}{dy}}_{1} = \frac{d\chi(y)}{dy}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2\Psi(x)}{dx^2} = \frac{d}{dx} \frac{d\Psi(x)}{dx} =\frac{d}{dx} \frac{d\chi(y)}{dy} = \frac{d^2\chi(y)}{dy^2}
\end{equation}
Now I plug everything back into the equation to get:
\begin{equation}
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2\chi(y)}{dy^2}+ay^2\chi (y) = \Big(E+\frac{b^2}{4a^2}\Big) \chi (y)
\end{equation}
And this is just the ordinary harmonic oscillator with a new Eigenvalue. Which I can just solve normally and then I plug back $\chi$ and $y$.
Is this method legit? Is there a better one?

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/812364/quantum-harmonic-oscillator-with-a-linear-perturbation

This is the standard technique: you're choosing a change of variables that converts a "new" problem into an old one. There are other approaches, e.g., perturbative, but this method has the decided advantage of giving the exact solution.
